# SpringMVC+Hibernate : criteria.list() is returning an empty list

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC with Hibernate, The aim is to get the table data and store it in a list.Here the entity class being used :

package com.bng.core.entity;

```
// default package
// Generated Oct 25, 2015 4:38:03 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * servicenames generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "servicenames")
public class ServiceNames implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String serviceName;

    public ServiceNames() {
    }

    public ServiceNames(String servicename) {
        this.serviceName = servicename;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "servicename", length = 25)
    public String getServiceName() {
        return this.serviceName;
    }

    public void setServiceName(String servicename) {
        this.serviceName = servicename;
    }


}
```

And the method used to get the list :

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public List<ServiceNames> getServiceNames() {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.APP_INFO, this.getClass().getName(), "Getting all Service names.");
        Session session = sessionFactoryGlobal.openSession();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(ServiceNames.class);
        List<ServiceNames> serviceNamesList = criteria.list();
        session.close();
        return serviceNamesList;
    }
```

When the method is called it returns an empty list. Please suggest where its going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sure your table `servicenames` has data. So such problem can be when `@Transactional` is not working properly. Try to get list without `@Transactional` by open and close a transaction manually.